# How to Work with two types of session (having two roles in a system, clients and admins)

Tags: php, html, session, admin

I got a problem with a system that I am developing. Is a Online Shop where I have two roles, separate each one with them tables (Clients and Administrators). In my web I got the User Side and the Admin Side, I have two sessions, one if user and all that it can do, and the session for the admins) The problem is that when i log in a user appears also that log in as an admin. For example: Maria Log in as User. When i go to admin and login as Agustin, the session that is from Maria, now is mine as and Admin. I cant explain it relly clearly, so there are some code.

So the solution I need is that I need the separate sessions. And If Maria is User it dont be confused with the Admin session.

```
Clients (when it logs in):

if ($_POST['contr_clie'] === $contr_clie) {
            // Verification success! User has loggedin!
            // Create sessions so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedInCliente'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['usuar_clie'];
            $_SESSION['ident_clie'] = $ident_clie;
            header('Location: ../index.php');
        } else {

Administrador (when it logs in):

if ($_POST['contr_admi'] === $contr_admi) {
            // Verification success! User has loggedin!
            // Create sessions so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedInAdmin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['usuar_admi'];
            $_SESSION['ident_admi'] = $ident_admi;
            header('Location: admin_panel.php');
        } else {
```

Comment: Why would you want to be logged in with 2 accounts?

Comment: Because of that, I need the two sessions separately because are two roles that are totally diferent.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But a user can not have 2 roles at the same time I imagine? Or, why would anyone wants to log in with 2 different accounts?

Comment: Yeah but the thing is that i have separate tables for each one, one is for the client and the other for the admin.